# How to predict order of a set of fractional differential equations?

Tags: fractional-calculus

I have a set of differential equations of the form:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = a[b-c*m-d*n-e*h]$$

$$\frac{dm}{dt} = p(v)$$

$$\frac{dn}{dt} = q(v)$$

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = r(v)$$

Using fde12 in MATLAB I can solve these equations and plot the graph. Now I need to solve the problem in the reverse order. I have  the values for vector $v$. Now how do I find the fractional order that fits these conditions?